# Google Maps V3 - Drawing rectangles with infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to draw out like ~15 rectangles, roughly ~40% opacity, on a google map -- what would be the best practice for doing this and also associating some HTML data with it?

An array and then foreaching through it? How would I make a mouseover (preferably) tooltip or at least on click?

Comment: Did the answer below help you? Its customary to click the arrow shape next to the answer if you believe it addressed your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a set of [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle) instances and use the [RectangleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RectangleOptions) to set the `fillOpacity` to `0.4`. The rectangle is a JavaScript object, so you are free to associate whatever data you want with any of the instances.

The rectangle also fires events for: `mouseover` and `click`, so you can trigger the DOM events you mention. In order to make the rectangle accept clicks, the `RectangleOptions` you pass to the constructor function may also include a member: `clickable`, which allows you to have the rectangle take click events if it is set to: `true`.

Or if you simply want to place a rectangular label on the Map and add some innerHTML content, almost like a post-it note on the map, you may be interested in the google-maps-utility-library [InfoBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox). It allows full control of styling and has mechanisms to give you control over event handling/propagation.

Comment: Also can look into the overlay class if you want more customization, this will let you directly insert html (with css and javascript associated) onto the map. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays)